# Removing z & m coordinates from KML files

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, grass-gis, coordinates

I've recently received some parcel data in shapefile format that has z & m coordinates (all = 0.0). The WKT for a typical parcel looks like this:

```
"MULTIPOLYGON (((2672464.560700002 711396.4336998622 0.0 0.0, 2672428.060700002 711369.2463998601 0.0 0.0, 2672373.310000001 711454.3723998595 0.0 0.0, 2672410.0600000033 711481.4969998623 0.0 0.0, 2672464.560700002 711396.4336998622 0.0 0.0)))"
```

This data is not being accepted by my Ruby GIS program/libraries (rgeo) when I try to parse the WKT. I could use GDAL/GRASS (little to no experience), Python (little to no experience) or some other Ruby library, but I'd prefer to sanitize this code of its 3D (Z) and M coordinates using QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GDAL:

It looks like you can specify the output type when creating polygons using the `SHPT` option (see the [docs for the shapefile driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html)). So you can specify if you want a simple 2d representation or 3d.

So in ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -lco SHPT=POLYGON -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_shapefile.shp input_shapefile.shp
```

This should work if your parcel data is polygons.

Answer (score 4):

You can work around the incorrect WKT formatting with sed (or any regular expression substitution app you have available):

```
cat invaildWKT | sed 's/ 0.0 0.0//g' > validWKT
```

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS... One 'hacky' workaround is to make a scratch layer, Clip it by your target layer, do a Multipart-to-Singlepart process, then generate your WKT. Since it's been clipped from the 2D layer in QGIS you can then re-render your WKT and it will only have Lat/Long. Finally, if needed, you can Spatial Join your original attributes to that result from your original target layer so that you have whatever those attributes were plus the new desired-format WKT.